# Testing a node.js server in jasmine without calling listen

Tags: node.js, tdd, jasmine

In attempting to write tests for a node server using jasmine and jasmine-node, my tests stall when I ask the server to `.listen(3000)`. Is there a way to have `listen` run async so it doesn't stop the rest of the tests while still calling it from within the tests?  Maybe I can test responses without even calling listen? Any good ideas/articles for node server testing?  I did see the expresso testing framework, but I'd like to stick with jasmine if possible.

When I call "listen" on an http or express server it sits there and listens. When .listen() is called in the test, the test waits for that command to finish before moving to the next. Since it is just listening in what I assume is something like a while(true) loop, that line never actually finishes for the test to go on to the next.

Simple server in coffeescript using express

```
class exports.Server

  constructor: (@port) ->
    express = require 'express'
    @express = express.createServer()
    io = require('socket.io').listen(@express)
    @express.use express.bodyParser()
    @status = "initialized"

  start: ->
    @express.listen @port
    console.log "Server listening on port " + @port
    @status = "running"
```

Simple Jasmine test, also in coffee.  Executed with Jasmine-Node.

```
Server = require("../src/server").Server

describe "server", ->
  server = new Server(3000)  

  it "initializes", ->
    expect(server.port).toEqual(3000)


  it "starts", ->
    server.start()
    console.log "FOO"  #never reached
```

Comment: I don't know of one `listen()` method that is blocking in Node.js. I suspect that the problem is somewhere else. Post some code.

Comment: Blocking may not be the right word.  But when I call "listen" on an http or express server it sits there and listens.  When `.listen()` is  called in the test, the test waits for that command to finish before moving to the next.  Since it is just listening in what I assume is something like a `while(true)` loop, that line never actually finishes for the test to go on to the next.

Comment: No, that's wrong. listen does not block.  The fact that your tests do not run probably lies in two areas 1) jasmine is screwing with you, 2) coffeescript is screwing with you

Comment: Removed all reference to "blocking"  sorry I used the wrong term.  The test still stops at `server.start()` no matter what the right term is.  I don't think the problem is with the coffee, seems in the jasmine end.  The script just sits there and does not finish.

Comment: Are you sure it never gets past the `start()` call? Some Node test frameworks are clever enough to detect that you've got something running (like a listening socket), and won't *end* the test (and move on to the next test) until you stop the listening socket and there's nothing left to do. I.e., it could be getting past the `start()` call, leaving the body of the test, but Jasmine sees that you're still doing something (perhaps waiting for async connections that are part of your test).

Comment: This is strange I could not reproduce the behavior you reported, FOO was well printed, and only then of course the event loop loops the server and you have to kill the test by hand, maybe there is some more background information you can provide?